# How do I create my own tokens?

Tags: entities, tokens

I use the Rules module. I want to add 1 to a CCK integer field on an action. Someone told me to create a custom token doing this addition.

So, I installed the tokenSTARTER module.

Now, how do I access the content profile (I load it in the rules chain) where the needed CCK field is in?

Comment: What exactly does the token need to output? Doesn't the Token module, or the CCK module provide a token for that?

Answer (score 8):

This module is very good for that: [Custom Tokens](http://drupal.org/project/token_custom).

> It gives the user the ability to create custom tokens for specific replacements that can improve other modules relying on the Drupal 7 token API or, for Drupal 6, the Token module.

Comment: How do I access the right field from the content_profile? I still need drupal api knowledge to do it. This module doesn't help me..

Comment: That module is good for creating custom tokens. I only need to create one though, and I'd prefer the PHP that generates the value for the token be in SVN not in the database. Does anyone have a simple example of how to create your own custom token?

Comment: Have a look at the API.txt in the token module, which explains about hook_token_values() and hook_token_list().

Comment: If you need an example of a token to work from, checkout the examples module

http://drupal.org/project/examples

and the token_example module. Thats a quick way to learn how to create tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Look for creation custom token for Drupal 7 at https://www.drupal.org/node/1308488

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.